# Compressing multiple files into each name using batch and 7zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a folder called CSV which contains multiple CSV files.

**My CSV Folder :**

```
abc_1.csv
abc_2.csv
abc_3.csv
```

I want to compress CSV files and save them to each name like this:

```
abc_1.csv.zip
abc_2.csv.zip
abc_3.csv.zip
```

My batch script:

```
for %%i in (*.csv) do 7z a -t7z "%%i.zip" "*.csv"
```

Zip files successfully created, but saved in one name like this:

contents of abc_1.csv.zip is:

```
abc_1.csv
abc_2.csv
abc_3.csv
```

I want the content of abc_1.csv.zip to contain only `abc_1.csv`. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

```bat
for %%i in (*.csv) do 7z a -t7z "%%i.zip" "*.csv"
```

You're adding all csv files into each zip file. You should do like this

```bat
for %%i in (*.csv) do 7z a -t7z "%%i.zip" "%%i"
```